# How to run react app in vscode without taking up the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using run and debug feature in vscode, how can I run a react app without it taking up the terminal window.

[image]

Using the default options available to me in vscode (node.js, chrome web app) are not much use to me.

The script I'd like to start it

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ...
}
```

I tried using the below launch.json but it takes up the terminal window

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "npm run start",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: start"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so? just add another terminal. or use an external console.